# How to get the ID of a parent element when any child clicked on newly created elements

Tags: javascript, events

I have a list of users that have been created via a loop (data from an API).
I am trying to return the ID of the parent element when any of its children elements are clicked.

Example: if a user clicks on any of the divs (.user-info, .user-name or .user-city) I want to be able to return the id of the parent div.user

I have tried looping through all child elements of user-list but I just get an empty object because the items were added after page loaded.

I have looked at event bubbling but it always bubbles up to user-list. I can't get it to stop at .user

I tried something like this, but it just returns each element and not the ID of the parent:

```js
const userList = document.querySelector(".user-list");

userList.addEventListener("click", event => {
  if (event.target.classList.contains('user')) {
    console.log(event.target)
  }
});
```

```html
<div class="user-list">
  <div class="user" id="1">
    <div class="user-photo">
      <img src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/men/91.jpg" alt="" />
    </div>
    <div class="user-info">
      <div class="user-name">josef moore</div>
      <div class="user-email email-wrap">josef.moore@example.com</div>
      <div class="user-city">winchester</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="user" id="2">
    <div class="user-photo">
      <img src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/men/98.jpg" alt="" />
    </div>
    <div class="user-info">
      <div class="user-name">alexander richardson</div>
      <div class="user-email email-wrap">alexander.richardson@example.com</div>
      <div class="user-city">stoke-on-trent</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="user" id="3">
    <div class="user-photo">
      <img src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/men/98.jpg" alt="" />
    </div>
    <div class="user-info">
      <div class="user-name">alexander richardson</div>
      <div class="user-email email-wrap">alexander.richardson@example.com</div>
      <div class="user-city">stoke-on-trent</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const userList = document.querySelector(".user-list");

userList.addEventListener("click", event => {
    var element = event.target;
    alert(element.closest('.user').id);
});
```

The closest() method of the Element interface returns the closest ancestor of the current element (or the current element itself).

**Note: Not supported in IE but polyfill is available.**

Refer: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest

[Working Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/Vardaman/a0egxub6/5/)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
const userList = document.querySelector(".user-list");

function findParent(element) {
    const parent = element.parentNode;
    if (parent.classList.contains('user')) {
        console.log(parent.id);
    } else if (parent) {
       findParent(parent);
    }
}

userList.addEventListener("click", event => {
    findParent(event.target);
});
```

[Working demo](https://jsfiddle.net/2793L5qr/1/)

Answer (score 0):

It may be considered "budget" approach, but you can walk up the element tree until you find an `user`, and check its `id`:

```js
document.getElementsByClassName("user-list").item(0).addEventListener("click",function(event){
  var target=event.target;
  var classes;
  while(!(classes=target.classList).contains("user-list")){
    if(classes.contains("user")){
      console.log(target.id);
    }
    target=target.parentElement;
  }
});
```

```html
<div class="user-list">
  <div class="user" id="1">
    <div class="user-photo">
      <img src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/men/91.jpg" alt="" />
    </div>
    <div class="user-info">
      <div class="user-name">josef moore</div>
      <div class="user-email email-wrap">josef.moore@example.com</div>
      <div class="user-city">winchester</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="user" id="2">
    <div class="user-photo">
      <img src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/men/98.jpg" alt="" />
    </div>
    <div class="user-info">
      <div class="user-name">alexander richardson</div>
      <div class="user-email email-wrap">alexander.richardson@example.com</div>
      <div class="user-city">stoke-on-trent</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="user" id="3">
    <div class="user-photo">
      <img src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/men/98.jpg" alt="" />
    </div>
    <div class="user-info">
      <div class="user-name">alexander richardson</div>
      <div class="user-email email-wrap">alexander.richardson@example.com</div>
      <div class="user-city">stoke-on-trent</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you user Jquery, this is code

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function() {
        $('.user-info, .user-name, .user-city').click(function() {
            var div_id = $(this).closest('.user').attr('id');
            console.log(div_id);
        });
    });
</script>
```